# Passing collection parameters when calling templates in StringTemplate

Tags: stringtemplate

Run into a bit of a snag using StringTemplate today. Were using StringTemplate 3.1 with .Net 3.5.

If I have a template that renders a collection of items, it renders fine if I call it directly.

However, if I call that template from another template and passing the collection through as a parameter, it fails to render at all.

The following is the basic template for rendering the collection. (Text is a property of the object we are rendering - System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem)

```
list.st

    $values: {
    $it.Text$
    }$
```

And this is the calling template.

```
callsList.st

    $list( 
    values={ $list$ } 
    )$
```

My question is, has anyone else run into this or does anyone know how to work around it? The strange thing is, we have other parts of our system rendering in a similiar style and they seem to work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try values=list.
Terence